# How can I link data-src images to internal page?

Tags: html, image, linker

This is what I have at http://www.hairattheritz.com/untitled.html
I love the way it resizes for various screen sizes, however I cannot find a way to make it link to the home page. Even the no script link I tried didn't work...

```
<figure id="logo">
    <div data-picture data-alt="Hair at the Ritz logo">
        <div data-src="images/hatr_logo_s.png"> </div>
        <div data-src="images/hatr_logo_m.png" data-media="(min-width: 45em)"> </div>
        <div data-src="images/hatr_logo.png" data-media="(min-width: 60em)"></div>
        <noscript>
            <img src="images/hatr_logo.png" alt="Hair at the Ritz Logo" name="logo"       id="logo">
        </noscript>
    </div>
</figure>
```

I'm hoping this is a simple   fix...somewhere
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying you want to link the images to your homepage? If so, why not just put the images inside of `<a></a>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the link to index.html is working for me.
Maybe you just can't see the image to click on because of several problems with your markup and JS.
You should check [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hairattheritz.com%2Funtitled.html) for more info.

You are using the $ Sign in your JS. I assume you want to use jQuery?
Then you have to include it first. For example put the following in your html file:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok I put that link in the head, and now my image shows up, so off to w3c validator thx...

Comment: No the image shows but doesn't link to index.html. Can the picturefill.js be edited to include a link? I've tried the html a href tags on each image, and nothing works. Seems like it could be so simple